# Issue with porting Python C library to "pure" C

Tags: python, c, pointers, struct, spi

I want to port a small library, that was written in C with the Python C API, to a pure C library/application. In the end I want this to work in C++ but I thought its better to get it working without the python dependency before focusing on getting it into C++.

This is the piece of code I want to port: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_DotStar_Pi/blob/master/dotstar.c

This controls a certain type of LEDs over SPI. In practice one can control many thousand LEDs with this piece of code. It's working great within Python but my ported code to a C application just does nothing as soon as I go beyond 256 LEDs. With below 256 LEDs, everything is working just fine.

So this seems to me either a type issue or allocation issue, that for some reason, doesn't cause a memory access violation. My test application does not crash, the LEDs simply don't do anything at all when going beyond the 256 threshold.

I have two pieces of code where I'm simply not 100% certain what Python was doing, that I substituted with my best educated guess.

All data for the LEDs is stored in a struct called DotStarObject, so I suspect the problem having to do with this struct.

Firstly I removed the PyObject_HEAD macro from the DotStarObject struct, as far as I understand it, all this does is add some stuff Python needs internally.

Next I changed the way the struct is being allocated when the DotStar_new function is being called.

Firstly I changed function type from `static PyObject *DotStar_new` to `static DotStarObject *DotStar_new` as it returns a pointer to DotStarObject struct.

The culprit that I think is causing my bug is the part where the struct is filled with data. Normally Python would allocate some memory here. As far as I understood Pythons `tp_alloc` all it does is allocate memory the size of the type being used (DotStarObject in this case).

So this:

```
PyTypeObject *type;
DotStarObject *self = NULL;
(...)
// Allocate space for LED data:
    if((!n_pixels) || ((pixels = (uint8_t *)malloc(n_pixels * 4)))) {
        if((self = (DotStarObject *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0))) {
            self->numLEDs    = n_pixels;
            self->dataMask   = 0;
            self->clockMask  = 0;
            self->bitrate    = bitrate;
            self->fd         = -1;
            self->pixels     = pixels; // NULL if 0 pixels
            self->pBuf       = NULL;   // alloc'd on 1st use
            self->dataPin    = dPin;
            self->clockPin   = cPin;
            self->brightness = 0;
            self->rOffset    = rOffset;
            self->gOffset    = gOffset;
            self->bOffset    = bOffset;
            Py_INCREF(self);
        } else if(pixels) {
            free(pixels);
        }
    }
```

became this (for now, missing the safeguard when allocation for `self` fails):

```
DotStarObject *self = (DotStarObject*)malloc(sizeof(DotStarObject));
(...)
if((!n_pixels) || ((pixels = (uint8_t *)malloc(n_pixels * 4)))) {
            self->numLEDs    = n_pixels;
            self->dataMask   = 0;
            self->clockMask  = 0;
            self->bitrate    = bitrate;
            self->fd         = -1;
            self->pixels     = pixels; // NULL if 0 pixels
            self->pBuf       = NULL;   // alloc'd on 1st use
            self->dataPin    = dPin;
            self->clockPin   = cPin;
            self->brightness = 0;
            self->rOffset    = rOffset;
            self->gOffset    = gOffset;
            self->bOffset    = bOffset;
    }
```

Did I misinterpret what `(DotStarObject *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0)` was doing or did I substitue it correctly with DotStarObject `*self = (DotStarObject*)malloc(sizeof(DotStarObject));` ?

My complete code can be found here if I missed some cruical information: http://pastebin.com/xddN9JMs

Comment: There is no language "C/C++"! Only the two **different** languages C and C++, so asking for "pure C/C++" is useless.

Comment: That is indeed confusing. I changed the title.
I only added C++ because thats where I want to go in the end but I guess it is not important for the question. I'm aware that these are different languages.

Comment: If you would use Ruby code if you wanted actually Brainfuck code, no, it does not matter. Otherwise it very well does. Ask for the question you want to use and use the appropriate code for that.

Comment: I meant its not important that I mention C++ here. I'm going for C here, I hope that is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for one thing I'd suspect this loop:

```
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < dotty->numLEDs; ++i){
    // setPixelColor(dotty,i,r,g,b);          
    setPixelColor(dotty,i,r,0,0);
}
```

You're using an 8-bit type for the index, which allows only 256 values regardless of the value of `dotty->numLEDs`.

Comment: Oh, that is the actually very obivous. I'm not sure if this happend before or after I hit the issue as I changed my test code quite often. It might just be added recently and unrelated but I will check that out and report back/accept the answer.

Comment: I feel pretty damn stupid. That was indeed the issue. Thanks so much for spotting this so quickly!